# Need to pass async call to a query parameter in firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My method won't compile because getVenueId(user) is async. I can't make ordersStream async because it is a stream.

```
 @override
      Stream<List<Order>> ordersStream(String venueId) {
         User user= User();
         final venueId = await getVenueId(user);
     return
service.collectionStream(path: APIPath.orders(), queryBuilder: (query) => query.where('venue.id', isEqualTo: venueId), builder: (data, documentId) => Order.fromJson(documentId, data));
```

here is myVenueId method..

```
Future<String> getVenueId(User user) async {
    final res = await Firestore.instance.document(APIPath.users(uid)).get();
    final data = res.data;
    user = User.fromJson(data);
    return user.venueIds;
  }
```

I need to use that as a query parameter

Answer (score 0):

You could use `getVenueId(user).then((value) => {//Do sth here})`;

```
Stream<List<Chat>> ordersStream(String venueId) {
    return get("url").then((venueId) {return service.collectionStream(path: APIPath.orders(), queryBuilder: (query) => query.where('venue.id', isEqualTo: venueId), builder: (data, documentId) => Order.fromJson(documentId, data));});
  }
```